# PrimeNG p-datatable set min width columns

Tags: primeng

I've a p-datatable responsive and I need to set min-width for each column. This to avoid on resize to have a column width too small.
My table is created in this way:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="listValue" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="200px" [loading]="loading" [responsive]="true">
     <p-column field="first" [style]="{'min-width':'90px'}">
          <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                  <span title="My first Column">My first Column</span>
          </ng-template>
    </p-column>
    ....
</p-dataTable>
```

It doesn't work. First column became smaller than 90px on resizing page.

Comment: You should try this code use class to set min-max width .[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51075942/how-set-primeng-data-table-columns-auto-fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51075942/how-set-primeng-data-table-columns-auto-fit)

Answer (score 2):

Like @opt SD said change

```css
.ui-table table {
    table-layout: unset
}
```

and then make the min-width to your table headers

Comment: This breaks the table markup - table cells are become different width than the headers (at version 9.1.3).

Comment: This worked for me, but I did have to add this as well to make the footer look good when the min-width is applied: `.ui-table { width: fit-content; }`

Answer (score 1):

Check the layout of your current table (**table-layout** CSS property)

In this case, your table's layout maybe is **FIXED**, you are not able to set min-width or max-width for the columns.